# Opening PDF, can't paste to specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I found some code online for opening a PDF, however when I import my PDF I can't seem to get it to open in the target sheet "Current". I can't see anything wrong with my variables but it is not selecting Current as the activesheet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub OpenPDF()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim IandC As Worksheet, Comparison As Worksheet, Previous As Worksheet, Current As Worksheet,     Flows As Worksheet
Dim appAA As Acrobat.AcroApp, docPDF As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim strFileName As String, intNOP As Integer, arrI As Variant
Dim intC As Integer, intR As Integer, intBeg As Integer, intEnd As Integer
Dim CurrentCell As Range

Set wkb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set IandC = wkb.Sheets("Instructions and CrossRef")
Set Comparison = wkb.Sheets("Comparison")
Set Previous = wkb.Sheets("Previous")
Set Current = wkb.Sheets("Current")
Set Flows = wkb.Sheets("Flows")

'Get Current Sheet
'Initialize Variables
Set Current = Application.ActiveSheet

With IandC
    Set CurrentCell = Range("L1")
End With

strFileName = "G:\CCLFG\IRG\FG\Cashflows\MPI Flows\" & CurrentCell & ".pdf"

'Select First Data Cell
Current.Range("A1").Select

Set appAA = CreateObject("AcroExch.App"): Set docPDF = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

docPDF.Open (strFileName)

'Extract Number of Pages From PDF File
intNOP = docPDF.GetNumPages

'Open PDF File
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strFileName, , True

'Loop Through All PDF File Pages
For intC = 1 To intNOP

'Go To Page Number
SendKeys ("+^n" & intC & "{ENTER}")

'Select All Data In The PDF File's Active Page
SendKeys ("^a"), True

'Right-Click Mouse
SendKeys ("+{F10}"), True

'Copy Data As Table
SendKeys ("c"), True

'Minimize Adobe Window
SendKeys ("%n"), True

'Paste Data In This Workbook's Worksheet
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Select Next Paste Cell
Current.Range("A" & Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 2).Select

'Maximize Adobe Window
SendKeys ("%x")
Next intC

'Close Adobe File and Window
SendKeys ("^w"), True

'Empty Object Variables
Set appAA = Nothing: Set docPDF = Nothing

'Select First Cell
Current.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```